# How can I optimise this repeated sequence sort?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, sequence

I'm sorting a list of dictionaries by one of the dict values and want to have a sorted sequence like 1,2,3,1,2,3,3 This is what I've come up with:

**Input:**

```
dicts = [{'name':'a', 'order':2}, {'name':'b', 'order':2}, {'name':'c', 'order':1}, {'name':'d', 'order':3}, {'name':'e', 'order':3}, {'name':'f', 'order':1}, {'name':'g', 'order':1}]
```

**Function:**

```py
from itertools import groupby, zip_longest
from typing import List

def seq_sort(input: List[dict]) -> List[dict]:
  new_seq = []
  # order the dicts
  ordered = sorted(input, key=lambda x: x['order'])
  # group the dicts
  group = [
    [p for p in v] for k, v in groupby(
      ordered,
      key=lambda x:x['order']
    )
  ]
  # put into new list in sequential order
  # grouped lists could be different lengths
  for groups in zip_longest(*group):
      for g in groups:
          if g is not None:
            new_seq.append(g)
  return new_seq

print(seq_sort(dicts))
```

**Output:**

```
[{'name': 'c', 'order': 1}, {'name': 'a', 'order': 2}, {'name': 'd', 'order': 3}, {'name': 'f', 'order': 1}, {'name': 'b', 'order': 2}, {'name': 'e', 'order': 3}, {'name':'g', 'order': 1}]
```

This works but I currently have brain fog and feel that this is not the best way to do it, how should I do this better?

Comment: Side-note: Why are you learning Python 2? It's been end of life for two months (and on life support for years before that).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I have converted to Python3

Comment: See the `roundrobin` function from the [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).